# Office 365 mailbox login error (something went wrong, There are too many active sessions connected to this mailbox)

Tags: office365

I have issue with office 365 account as one of the user is not able to login to office 365 mailbox.

He is able to login office 365 but not able to access e-mail as it is giving an error "something went wrong", There are too many active sessions connected to this mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

There are something you might want to check:

1. Have you assigned a license/mailbox to the user.
2. If you did, can you login the user via OWA: mail.office365.com.
3. If still no luck, clean cache and reset IE, also try using different browser.

Have a look at the following link, it has the similar problem:
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/168742.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with on-prem Exchange 2013 - I just waited 5 minutes and tried again and it worked OK.